# Cloud Based Database to store data for Business Intelligence

Tags: database, cloud-service, cloud-storage, amazon

I'm currently looking for a cloud based database. The purpose of the Database will be to store data that I'll retrieve from other websites through API. It needs to be able to store the data with relative ease and let me access the data to retrieve it, as I'll be using the data in another software. After modifying the data in this other software I might have to store it in the database again. The type of software I'll most likely be using the data in is a Business Intelligence Software.

The data I'll be storing will most likely come from CSV, JSON, XML, or SAF-T files. It would be preferable if the solution required minimal work to make importing data from these files possible.

I currently have access to the free tier of Amazon Web Services which seems to have several options though I'm not sure which one is the best for my purpose. If anyone have a suggestion involving the alternatives on AWS that would be prefered though I'm open to other alternatives.

The solution have to be free or atleast have a free alternative so that it can be tested.